Tkinter Check Combo Box Issue
I am trying to create a combo box with a checkbox against each item. I am not able to select multiple items at one go as every time I have to click the drop-down and select one. Also, It collapses every time I select one item.
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

main = Menubutton(root,text="Various Dates")
main.grid()
main.menu = Menu(main,tearoff=0)
main['menu'] = main.menu

Date0 = StringVar()
Date1 = StringVar()
Date2 = StringVar()
Date3 = StringVar()

main.menu.add_checkbutton(label='22/03/2024',variable=Date0)
main.menu.add_checkbutton(label='24/03/2024',variable=Date1)
main.menu.add_checkbutton(label='26/03/2024',variable=Date2)
main.menu.add_checkbutton(label='28/03/2024',variable=Date3)

main.pack()
root.mainloop()

The above code creates a simple Dropbox but every time it collapses after selecting an option. I need the dropdown to be open until I select multiple options and once I click dropdown it should collapse like below.


python - Keep a menu open in Tkinter - Stack Overflow - it assigns function which reopen menu after clicking. But problem is to show it in correct position.

other idea: don't use Menu but create own code for this. You can use Frame to keep checkboxes and .place() to display it in any place. OR maybe you should use normal dialog window for this.

@furas Thanks for your reply  but I have 25 such items and can't place them on frame and that's the reason i want to place them in combo box.

why you can't put all comboboxes in one Frame and display this Frame instead of using Menu. You can add to menu button which shows Frame with all comboxes, and you can decide when to hide Frame. Seems Tkinter has no method to keep it open - so you have to create own widget for this.
